# How to Get Parent with Child Products or Siblings Products?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Product Table which is only one level deep. Means, I don't have child of child. My table structure sample is,

```
ID Name ParentID
----------------
1   A     NULL
2   B     1
3   C     NULL
4   D     3
5   E     1
```

Now my input is ID = 1, it should give me,

```
ID Name ParentID
----------------
1   A     NULL
2   B     1
5   E     1
```

if input is ID = 2, it should give me,

```
ID Name ParentID
----------------
1   A     NULL
2   B     1
5   E     1
```

if input is ID = 3, it should give me,

```
ID Name ParentID
----------------
3   C     NULL
4   D     1
```

Because 2 don't have any children, I selected the siblings

Comment: What query have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
declare @var int
set @var=2

select top 1 @var=ISNULL(Parentid, id) from YourTable where ID=@var

select 
  * 
From 
  YourTable 
where
  ID=@var

union all

select 
  * 
From 
  YourTable 
where
  ParentID=@var
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1309/5)

Comment: Sorry, I forget, I need to include parent as well. Please see my edit